# PostgreSQL - How can I pass parameter when I use DO $$?

Tags: c#, postgresql

I am totally new to PostgreSQL and I definitely dislike it but anyway, here I am.

I had this piece of working code where I am simply passing parameters as we "usually" do to my query:

```
var query = $@"
   INSERT INTO TableTwo (
      customer_id,
      site_id,
      item_id,
      qoh,
    )
     SELECT 
        customer_id,
        site_id,
        item_id,
        qoh
    FROM 
        TableOne 
    WHERE
        customer_id = @Customer_id";

await dbConnection.ExecuteAsync(query, new { Customer_id });
```

Now I have been asked to add an if statement at the top of the query to check if TableOne exists - I have spent already some time to figure out the syntax but I now got it right ALTHOUGH my parameter is not recognized anymore. This is my current version:

```
var query = $@"
    DO $$  
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 
                  FROM information_schema.tables 
                  WHERE table_schema = CURRENT_SCHEMA AND table_name = 'TableOne'
        )
        THEN
            INSERT INTO TableTwo (
                customer_id,
                site_id,
                item_id,
                qoh
                )
                SELECT 
                    customer_id,
                    site_id,
                    item_id,
                    qoh
                FROM 
                    TableOne 
                WHERE
                    customer_id = @Customer_id;
        END IF;
    END
    $$;";
    
    await dbConnection.ExecuteAsync(query, new { Customer_id });
```

So I had to add "DO $$" and a bunch of semicolumn around just to get it to run again but now I am getting the following error: *Npgsql.PostgresException: '42883: operator does not exist: @ character varying'*

I've tried a few more options but I can't get it to work. Can anyone help, please?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Dynamic tables are sooooo bad...

Comment: accually from docs `DO` - *execute an anonymous code block - The code block is treated as though it were the body of a **function with no parameters***

Comment: Thank you @Selvin - you helped me out thinking a different way of resolving the situation

Comment: @Selvin dynamic tables may be "soooooo bad" but sometimes people need to use certain things as they are constrained by the existing code / standards etc. Adding a disparaging comment like this adds nothing to help OP in finding a solution to their problem.

Answer (score 2):

I've got it working - it is a simple fix that seems like working so far, I have basically used string interpolation rather than passing the parameter.

Here you go and thanks for the help

```
var query = $@"
    DO $$  
    BEGIN
        IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = CURRENT_SCHEMA AND table_name = 'TableOne')
        THEN
            INSERT INTO TableTwo (
                customer_id,
                site_id,
                item_id,
                qoh
                )
                SELECT 
                    customer_id,
                    site_id,
                    item_id,
                    qoh
                FROM 
                    TableOne 
                WHERE
                    customer_id = '{Customer_id}';
        END IF;
    END
    $$;";
    
await dbConnection.ExecuteAsync(query);
```

Although as @Selvin said - this is not the best solution and apparently it leaves the code open to SQL Injection attack.

Any better ways to do that?

Comment: [not a great choice if `Customer_id` can came from user's input](https://xkcd.com/327/) ... it would be better to use two queries: in first check if table exists and in second do normal insert with parameter